# How to create a link

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In my VF page i want to add a link to an another object for creating new record of the object.
Can anybody help me to find the solution for this problem.
Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get to the standard 'new record' page for an object, you can use the global `$Action` variable with `URLFOR` like so:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action.Account.New ) }">New Account</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

This syntax also supports dynamic binding:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:repeat var="object" value="objects">
    <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action[object].New ) }">New {! object}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

You can also pass parameters to the new page using the optional arguments of `URLFOR`:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action.Account.New, null, [acc2='Account Name'] ) }">New Account</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

If you want to navigate directly to another Visualforce page you can use the `$Page` global variable:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:outputLink value="{! $Page.MyVfPage }">Go to my VF Page</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```